# all possible permutations (`1,2,4`) from my string and the position he is in

Tags: vb.net

how to extract only the values ​​from this string (1,2,4), but in their order. because "4" does not exist in my string, it will not be displayed.

```
3,7,1,2,3,5,2,3,5,6,9,6,7,5,9,3,7,9,1,5
```

in the textbox I will have to display

```
1,2
1,2
```

or

```
1
2
1
2
```

now displays

```
1
2
2
1
```

but at the same time to be able to recognize the position, that is to say it should result:
the first possible combination:

```
2,3 (1 is in position 2, and 2 is in position 3.)
```

the second possible combination will be:

```
2,6 (1 is in position 2, and 2 is in position 6.)
```

and so on for all possible combinations.

and so on such a model.

Code:

```
  Dim strWords() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(","c)
        For i As Integer = 0 To TextBox1.Text.Split(","c).Length - 1
            If Val(strWords(i)) = "1" Then
                TextBox2.AppendText("1=" & strWords(i) & vbNewLine)
            ElseIf Val(strWords(i)) = "2" Then
                TextBox2.AppendText("2=" & strWords(i) & vbNewLine)
            ElseIf Val(strWords(i)) = "4" Then
                TextBox2.AppendText("4=" & strWords(i) & vbNewLine)
            End If
        Next
```

let's take another example:

```
2,4,5,1,8,1,3,4,1,5,6,9,3,9,4,5,6,8,9,4
```

now shows me: display

```
2
4
1
1
4
1
4
4
```

I want to display from smallest to largest (`1,2,4`), but at the same time to recognize the strwords in the string. and where that digit position is. in short all possible permutations (`1,2,4`) of that string. but at the same time to recognize where each position is. that is, the first possible combination of `1,2,4` `(position 3,0,1)`

any help to build such an algorithm is welcome. thanks!

Comment: Could you use String.Split() to pull it into an array, then use Array/IEnumberable methods?

Comment: it may be possible, I will document myself